# Flutter slider not working when separated into individual files

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently working with Flutter/Dart and I have created a separate widget as a class for a project to experiment with reusability.

The problem I've encountered is that the slider doesn't slide when built in the way shown below, despite passing onChanged setState to the SliderWidget. I am trying to have a base slider class that can be reused in multiple widgets rather than a Slider() widget in a separate dart file which I can include another file, that does work.

I have tried reworking this as a mixin but that did not fix the problem. Is this because I have too many widgets nested? If I change the SliderWidget reference in the ScaleWidget.dart file to just use a Slider widget, everything works but at the loss of being able to have more control over the Slider base class.

sliderWidget.dart - base class for the slider widget

```
class SliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  double value;
  double min;
  double max;
  String label;
  dynamic onChanged;
  dynamic onChangeStart;
  dynamic onChangeEnd;

  SliderWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.value,
      required this.min,
      required this.max,
      required this.label,
      required this.onChanged,
      this.onChangeStart,
      required this.onChangeEnd})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SliderWidgetState createState() => _SliderWidgetState();
}

class _SliderWidgetState extends State<SliderWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      value: widget.value,
      min: widget.min,
      max: widget.max,
      label: widget.label,
      onChanged: (double value) => widget.onChanged,
      onChangeStart: (double value) => widget.onChangeStart,
      onChangeEnd: (double value) => widget.onChangeEnd,
    );
  }
}
```

ScaleWidget.dart - Built using SliderWidget.dart

```
class ScaleWidget_fromSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  dynamic widgetData;
  dynamic detailData;

  ScaleWidget_fromSlider(
      {Key? key, required this.widgetData, required this.detailData})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScaleWidget_fromSliderState createState() => _ScaleWidget_fromSliderState();
}

class _ScaleWidget_fromSliderState extends State<ScaleWidget_fromSlider> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Visibility(
      visible: widget.detailData != null,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    "Scale:"
                  )),
              Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Text(
                    (widget.detailData?.Current as double)
                  )),
            ],
          ),
          SliderWidget(
            value: widget.detailData?.Current as double,
            min: widget.detailData?.Min as double,
            max: widget.detailData?.Max as double,
            label: widget.detailData?.Current.toString() ?? "",
            onChanged: (double value) {
              if (mounted) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.detailData?.Current = value;
                });
              }

               
            },
            onChangeEnd: (double value) {
             
            },
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main.dart scaffold

```
ScaleWidget_fromSlider(
                  widgetData: widget.widgetData,
                  detailData: detailData?.Scale),
```

Comment: you need `onChanged: onChanged,` the same for `onChsngeStart` / `onChangeEnd`

Comment: It did resolve with that change. For my own clarification, there isn't any need to (double value) => widget.onChangeEnd to pass arguments then?

Comment: you either need `foo: foo` or `foo: (double value) => foo(value)`, not `foo: (double value) => foo` since it just returns your callback - it does not call it